# Replace String pattern with new string

Tags: c, string, design-patterns, replace

**I could really use some help with this question...**

- `char *replace(char *s, char *pat, char *rep)`

  *Returns a copy of the string s, but with each instance of `pat` replaced with `rep`. Note that `len(pat)` can be less than, greater than, or equal to `len(rep)`. The function allocates memory for the resulting string, and it is up to the caller to free it. For example, if we call `replace("Fiore X", "X", "sucks")`, what is returned is the new string `Fiore sucks` (but remember, `pat` could be longer than an individual character and could occur multiple times).*

I've managed to determine whether the pattern occurs in the original string, but I run into a problem if the pattern occurs more than once. I also haven't got to the part of creating a new string with the replaced text. I'm not allowed to use any functions from `<string.h>`.  (I'm still very new to C)

```
char *replace(char *s, char *pat, char *rep){

    char *a = malloc(300);
    char *pa = s;
    int patLen = 0;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; pat[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        patLen++;
    } 
    int ogLen = patLen;
    while(*s != '\0')
    {
        if(*s == *pat)
        {
            s++;
            pat++; 
            patLen--;
            while(*s == *pat)
            {
                s++;
                pat++;
                patLen--;
            }
            if(patLen == 0)
            {
                printf("This is a pattern");
                patLen = ogLen;
            }
        }
        s++;

    }   
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't use string.h functions, I'd write a few string utility functions to count string length, compare strings and copy strings. This will make your code easier to understand.  I'd make 2 passes through string s: first time would count the occurrences of pat.  Then I can calculate the size of the new string: length(s) + occurrences * (length(rep) - length(pat).  Allocate the new string.  Now pass through string s again, copying into new string but whenever occurrence of pat is found, copy rep instead.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, not using string.h, it can be done.

First thing, you're doing pat++, but never going back. after finding the first occurrence of the first letter of the pat string, you're never coming back to the start of the string to make other comparisons in the future.

Using s++ is fine, as you don't need to come back to the start of this string, but for pat I would advise you to use index, and assess pat[i]. Nevertheless, if you keep track on how many times you advanced with pat++, you should be able to pat-- the exact amount (by the way, recursion would be an elegant way to do so without creating an int to keep track of how many times you advanced)

On the second while, just for safety, I would include &&*s!='\0'. And for proccess reasons, add &&patLen!=0. If you don't include this last one, you'll do one extra s++, and lose one possible starting point.

And finally, just a printf won't solve your problems, you should be able to track where the pattern was found (easily done with an array of ints) so you can go back and replace it.

The replacing gets trick when pat and rep have different sizes. I would create some additional functions, to make room for chars (in case rep>pat), and to eliminate some chars (if rep